# Asking questions about related topics

Tags: support

I'd like to clarify the rules of Stack Overflow.

If I find a thread that partly answers a question that I wish to ask, should I ask the question as a comment in that thread, as an answer in that thread or should I start a new thread and provide a link to the related thread?

Comment: Thread? *Thread??* ***THREAD???***

Answer (score 2):

You should go with the third option, starting a new question and linking to the old one. Make sure you make the differences between your questions clear, explicitly stating what the other question's answers failed to address; otherwise, people may think it is the same question and mark it as a duplicate.